OpenPlatform (Total.js): node index.js gives Error: Cannot find module ../openplatform-master/plugins/.DS_Store/index.js
My question is about OpenPlatform.
When I run the command: node index.js from the Manual Installation instructions, I get the following output and error below:
Note:

I'm running zsh shell from a Sonoma 14.2.1 Terminal
I'm using npm version 10.7.0 and node v22.1.0
I've tried npm install and npm install debug --save, but the same error & output persist.
Any tips and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Output & Error
openplatform-master % node index.js           
> DEBUG PID: 66116 (v5)
ERROR ======= 2024-06-16 15:14:35: Error: Cannot find module '../openplatform-master/plugins/.DS_Store/index.js'
Require stack:
- ../openplatform-master/node_modules/total5/index.js
- ../openplatform-master/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1224:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at F.load (/openplatform-master/node_modules/total5/index.js:855:11) 
====================================================
PID           : 66117
Node.js       : v22.1.0
Total.js      : v5000
OS            : darwin 23.2.0
Memory        : 7.69 MB / 10.03 MB
User          : **
====================================================
Name          : OpenPlatform
Version       : 1.0.0
Date (utc)    : 2024-06-16 15:14:35
Mode          : debug
Compiled      : undefined files (0ms)
====================================================
Directory     : ../openplatform-master
node_modules  : ../openplatform-master/node_modules/
====================================================

run OpenPlatform via the command node index.js from the Manual Installation Instructions

Remove the .DS_Store file from the plugins directory. I have checked the repository (https://github.com/totaljs/openplatform/tree/master/plugins), and it doesn't contain the mentioned file. We will improve the Total.js framework by adding filters for these kinds of files.

The fix for me was to update npm, nvm, and node per these instructions here (I updated npm to 10.7.0, nvm to 20, and node to v20.14.0) : https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager (thank you anyways!)
